# getting list of children processes by a background shell function

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a bash script, in which I call function in a background:

```
process_manager $1 $2 $3 &
```

The function runs / executes commands that are passed as an argument in the background.

How can I get a list of child processes in the function process_manager ?

I tried doing that:

```
process_manager () {
  count=$1
  interval=$2
  cmd=$3
  bash_pid=$$
  last_pid=$!

  echo "bash_pid: $bash_pid, ppid: $PPID, last_pid: $last_pid"
  $cmd &
  $cmd &
  sleep 30 &
}

process_manager $1 $2 $3 &
process_manager $1 $2 $3 &
process_manager $1 $2 $3 &
```

But here function process_manager won't display $! or $last_pid when its called for the first time.

How should I get $last_pid in that situation and to be able to access children process list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$$` contains the pid of the shell that was *executed* to interpret the *script*. It's the same in every subshell of that shell.

`$!` contains the pid of the last child command run in background (with `&` or coproc or process substitution)

In the command run itself in background, `$!` it not set. `$!` is meant for the parent so it can wait or kill its child.

`bash` has a `$BASHPID` variable that contains the pid of the *current subshell*.

It's not always clear what process it is.

In:

```
echo "$BASHPID"
```

It's the pid of the process that interpreted that `echo` command, but in

```
/bin/echo "$BASHPID"
```

which does fork a process, `$BASHPID` does not report the pid of that forked process but the pid of the parent. While in:

```
/bin/echo "$BASHPID" &
```

(the only difference being that the parent doesn't wait for its child), `$BASHPID` reports the pid of the forked process:

```
$ bash -c 'echo "$$"; echo "$BASHPID"; /bin/echo "$BASHPID"; /bin/echo $BASHPID &'
3264
3264
3264
3266
```

In you case though, you can safely do:

```
process_manager () {
  pid_of_last_command_run_in_background=$!
  mypid=$BASHPID
  cmd &
  cmd1pid=$!
  cmd &
  cmd2pid=$!
}
```

`$pid_of_last_command_run_in_background` will be the pid of the last command run in background (by the current subshell, or its parent or its grandparent). That's why you get something in `$last_pid` in the second run (the pid of the previous process_manager) and not in the first.